# como ocultar una fila de una tabla dinámica en PHP

Tags: php

hola a todos necesito de sus conocimientos lo que requiero es que tengo un array asociativo en la cual maqueto mi tabla.
Lo que necesito es ocultar unas filas para que no aparescan en la vista del usario

mi codigo es la siguiente:
PHP: tabla

```
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th scope="col-sm">Id</th>
      <th scope="col-sm">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col-sm">Horas de trabajo</th>
      <th scope="col-sm">Puesto</th>
      <th scope="col-sm">Pagos</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

PHP: foreach para obtner el array y colocarlo en la tabla

```
<?php foreach ($DatosUsuarios as $key => $Usuario) : ?>
```

PHP: este if lo coloco, son lasque quiero ocultarlos no se como

```
<?php if($Usuario['Nombre'] == "Juan" && $Usuario['Nombre'] == "Maria" && $Usuario['Nombre'] == "Jose" && $Usuario['Nombre'] == "Jesus") : ?>

         <tr class="<?=$res?>">
             <td><?= $centro['Nombre']?></td>
             <td><?= $centro['trabajoHoras']?></td>
             <td><?= $centro['Puesto']?></td>
             <td><?= $centro['Pagos']?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endif;?>
```

espero y me haya ebtendido

Comment: Cambia los `==`  por `!=` en ese if y no aparecerán esos nombres

Comment: vale lo checare